# param is missing or the value is empty: gallery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, dragonfly-gem

The problem is with "strong parameters" in rails.
I use dragonfly for uploading images.

The problem is that if I send an empty form I do not get any parameters for error handling. What can be the reason?

Controller:

There is still also a method "Create" which saves the image in the database and sends the user to a page with pictures.

```
def index
  @gallery = Gallery.new
  @galleries = Gallery.all
end

def create
  @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)

  if @gallery.save
    redirect_to galleries_path, flash: { success: 'Your Image was successfully save.' }
  else
    redirect_to :back,          flash: { alert: "Your Image don't save." }
  end
end

def gallery_params
  params.require(:gallery).permit(:image)
end
```

Views:

```
= form_for @gallery do |f|
  = f.file_field :image
  = f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn bth-primary btn-lg'
```

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"8eotQtkj8SElqJLdHuOX8r+dWrCJRWTmVcyfd1mSLD/8MjWw/ElH/HCxZFSJ6oOWaxpbLbn4kAg5nlFycsgjHg==", "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Comment: what do you mean by " I do not get any parameters for error handling"?

Comment: what you are getting is perfectly fine and as expected.

Comment: If you mean that you don't get any validation error, perhaps that's due to the `image` field is not mandatory. You should post your `Gallery` model

Comment: I have to get the blank option to display the error.
example: image Field empty.

Comment: But it is mandatory. `validates :image, presence: true`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the model. The error is from the `params.require(:gallery).permit(:image)`. you see `require(:gallery)` actually requires `gallery` to be present.

Comment: if I'm not mistaken should come empty parameter  `gallery: {}`

Comment: It is the expected behavior, see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require

Comment: `require` will throw an error if the param is missing. just as it is doing now. You might try `.permit` instead of `.require`. Just an idea. Im a bit rusty on Rails nowadays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, see the documentation for [ActionController::Parameters#require](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require)

What I usually do in those cases is catch the exception and display a flash message to notify the user. You could also manually add an error to the model.

```
def create
  @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)

  if @gallery.save
    redirect_to galleries_path, flash: { success: 'Your Image was successfully save.' }
  else
    redirect_to :back, flash: { alert: "Your Image don't save." }
  end
rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
  redirect_to :back, flash: { alert: "Please attach an image." }
end
```